# AVPlayer: AirPlay button shows up in control center even though allowsExternalPlayback is set to NO

Tags: ios, avplayer, airplay

I've got an instance of AVPlayer which plays some media, but I don't want user to be able to stream it via AirPlay. So I set `allowsExternalPlayback` property of AVPlayer to `NO`. However it doesn't seem to affect AirPlay button in control center, so it stays visible. Is there any way to hide the button?

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: Any luck with this?  Still a problem...