# AVplayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO is not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avplayer

I have been trying to disable airplay for videos and setting

```
AvPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
```

But it is not working for me. I am still able to go to control center and cast video to apple tv.

Do I need to set some other parameters else here?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755169/avplayer-airplay-button-shows-up-in-control-center-even-though-allowsexternalpl

Comment: Did you find out anything on this?

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can use `usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive=false` property to disable AirPlay. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1624255-usesexternalplaybackwhileexterna

Comment: The documentation actually states: `The value of this property has no effect if allowsExternalPlayback is false.`